# JMeter - JSON Extractor extracts correct value in one case but null in other case

Tags: json, jmeter, json-path-expression

I have two requests that return response with similar JSON structure. When I try to  use JSON extractor on one, it works properly but when I try to extract value in the same way from the second one, it doesn't work. But let's cut to the chase.

My first response looks like this:

```
{
    "values": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Fendi",
            "logoId": null,
            "belongsToUser": true
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Jean Paul Gaultier",
            "logoId": null,
            "belongsToUser": true
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Nike",
            "logoId": null,
            "belongsToUser": false
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Adidas",
            "logoId": null,
            "belongsToUser": true
        }
    ]
}
```

And I try to extract ID of the object that "belongsToUser": false in this JSON Extractor:

```
JSON path expression: values[?(@.belongsToUser == false)].id
Match No.: 0
Default Values: null
```

And it works perfecty fine.

However, when I try this way on my second response, it doesn't work.
The response looks like this:

```
{
    "values": [
        {
            "id": 12,
            "brandName": "Fendi",
            "productCategoryName": "Shoes",
            "size": "38",
            "colorNames": [
                "color_green"
            ],
            "date": 1536537600000,
            "imageId": null,
            "title": "Money",
            "numberOfOffers": 0,
            "status": "ONGOING"
        },
        {
            "id": 13,
            "brandName": "Fendi",
            "productCategoryName": "Shoes",
            "size": "38",
            "colorNames": [
                "color_green"
            ],
            "date": 1536537600000,
            "imageId": null,
            "title": "Exchange",
            "numberOfOffers": 0,
            "status": "ONGOING"
        }
    ]
}
```

I try to get id of object that has title variable = "Money" with JSON extractor:

```
JSON path expression: values[?(@.title == 'Money')].id
Match No.: 0
Default Values: null
```

But it doesn't find id value and sets my JMeter variable to null.
I also tried to leave Money unquoted or in double quotes and tried different JSON path expresions, like

```
$.values[?(@.title == 'Money')].id
$..[?(@.title == 'Money')].id
$.[?(@.title == 'Money')].id
```

But none of these seems to work. Do you have any idea how my JSON path expression shoud look to work properly?
And why doesn't it work in second case when it works in first? Is it because objets in second response have inside array?

Comment: You JSON extractor is working fine for me, check if you are using another post processor with the same variable name after this one.

Comment: @ararar no, I don't use the same variable name in following post processors. Only in following requests.

Answer (score 0):

I have used your code and it is giving the correct results. Please check the below images. 
[image]

[image]
I have tried with version 3.1 also and it is working fine.

Hope this helps.

Check the below image for different types of options in view result tree.
[image]

Comment: For me it's not working and my variable is null. Is this "JSON path tester" in results tree some plug-in or build-in option cause I can't find it. I use JMeter 4.0

Comment: It comes along and is not a additional plugin. Run the test and in the "View result tree" sampler..click the dropdown where JSON Path Tester is shown. Default value of that is text, so you have to select JSON Path tester.

Comment: Thank you. When I tried it, it returns: "Exception: Could not parse token starting at position 8. Expected ?, ', 0-9, * " - so that's why it doesn't work, but I don't know why this error happens.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the same issue. But, it seems like a parsing issue due to some missing character or malformed request/response.

Answer (score 0):

The `$..[?(@.title == 'Money')].id` expression should work just fine:

[image: JMeter JSON Path Tester Conditional]

Most probably your JMeter installation is corrupt and you experience some form of [jar hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell) due to some clashing library in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) (it might be caused by presence of deprecated [JSON Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) or similar) . So I would recommend obtaining clean [latest](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) version of JMeter and trying out your test on it. If you're using any plugins - install them using [JMeter Plugin Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

---

If you are not in position to re-install JMeter you can try to get to the bottom of the issue by looking into *jmeter.log* file. If there are no suspicious entries - add the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.extractor.json" level="debug" />
```